# Cannot implicity convert type object to unityengine.Vector3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to place six objects(ball) on scene. I think the code look workable but I receive a console message. The message :

> "Assets/GameScripts/Instance.cs(26,40): error CS0266: Cannot
>   implicitly convert type `object' to`UnityEngine.Vector3'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Instance : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject ball;

```
public ArrayList coordinateContainer = new ArrayList();



// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    coordinateContainer.Add(new Vector3(1f,1f,1f));
    coordinateContainer.Add(new Vector3(2f,1f,1f));
    coordinateContainer.Add(new Vector3(3f,1f,1f));
    coordinateContainer.Add(new Vector3(4f,1f,1f));
    coordinateContainer.Add(new Vector3(5f,1f,1f));
    coordinateContainer.Add(new Vector3(6f,1f,1f));


    //ball.transform.position = new Vector3(1f,1f,1f);
    ball.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;

    for (int i = 0; i <  6; i++) {
        ball.transform.position = coordinateContainer[i];
        Instantiate(ball,ball.transform.position,ball.transform.rotation);
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using an `ArrayList` the vectors are being stored as `objects`. Try this

```
ball.transform.position = (Vector3)coordinateContainer[i];
```

You may be better off with `List<Vector3>` instead of an ArrayList so that you can avoid the casting (as `List<T>` can only hold objects of type `T`).

Comment: 'Assets/GameScripts/Instance.cs(26,74): error CS0077: The `as' operator cannot be used with a non-nullable value type `UnityEngine.Vector3'' - I receive that message when I try "as Vector3".

Comment: @HalilCosgun - I've updated the answer to use direct casting. This is another good reason to use a `List<T>` because you're looping through all the objects in the `coordinateContainer` and if it can't be cast to a `Vector3` object then an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) It works. Thanks for advice, I will use List.

Comment: @HalilCosgun - You're welcome. Depending on how often it's called you may also notice a speed improvement with a List because Vector3 is a value type which means it has to be boxed and unboxed when stored and retrieved in an ArrayList. With a List, you avoid the boxing/unboxing performance hit.